# Big $\mathcal{O}$ notation for multiple parameters?

Tags: computer-science, asymptotics, computational-complexity

The following is an excerpt from *Introduction to Algorithms* by Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest, and Clifford Stein (aka CLRS):

> $\mathcal{O}(g(n,m)) = \{ f(n,m): \text{there exist positive constants }c, n_0,\text{ and } m_0\text{ such that }0 \le f(n,m) \le cg(n,m)\text{ for all }n \ge n_0\text{ or }m \ge m_0\}$

Consider an alternative possible extention of Big-$\mathcal{O}$ notation to multiple variables:

> $\mathcal{O}(g(n,m)) = \{ f(n,m):\text{there exist positive constants $c$, $n_0$, and $m_0$ such that }0 \le f(n,m) \le cg(n,m)\text{ for all }n \ge n_0\text{ and }m \ge m_0\}$

Are there any reasons why the first definition is used as an extension instead of the second?

Comment: Sorry but I cannot find any difference between these two definitions. Could you please point out that explicitly?

Comment: @WangfanFu: The connective between $n\ge n_0$ and $m\ge m_0$ is an "or" in one version and an "and" in the other.

Comment: @sadf : Please notice the recent edit.  You do not need to put $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ OUTSIDE of $\TeX$.  Just use backslashes, thus: \{f(n,m)\}.  You'll see this: $\{f(n,m)\}$.  When you put the outside of $\TeX$, then standard spacing and size conventions are not followed.

Comment: related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/105280/order-mistake-definition-in-clrs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. I think the reason why the first definition is "better" is that it can be stated independently of the number of parameters as:

> Let $f,g:X\to\mathbb R_+$ for some discrete space $X$. We say that $f \in \mathcal O(g)$ iff there is a positive constant $c$ such that $f(x)\le cg(x)$ for *all but finitely many $x$*.

Then the usual one-parameter definition results when we take $X$ to be $\mathbb N$, and the one you quote from CLRS when we take $X$ to be $\mathbb N^2$.

In contrast, your proposed second definition would allow *unbounded* functions such as
$$f(n,m) = \begin{cases} n+m & n=100 \lor m=100 \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
to be $O(1)$, which doesn't seem to be useful for reporting algorithmic complexity.

---

More abstractly, remember that asymptotics are always defined relative to some limit $x\to x_0$. In the case above the limit is $x\to (+\infty,+\infty)$. Limits involving infinity are often treated as a special case in real analysis, but there's a natural topology on $\mathbb N^2\cup\{\infty\}$ such that the definition above is equivalent to

> We say that $f\in\mathcal O_{x\to x_0}(g)$ iff there is a positive constant $c$ such that $f\le cg(x)$ everywhere in some neighborhood of $x_0$, except possibly at $x_0$ itself.

This view encompasses the asymptotics for $x\to 0$ we see in analysis. Additionally, it offers the opportunity to get your second definition back in the game, if you redefine the topology on $\mathbb N^2\cup\{\infty\}$ to give $\infty$ smaller neigborhoods.

Then the distinction between the two definitions you quote is simply that they are based on *two different limits*.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great answer. But what is CLRS? Would you mind looking at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1484899/15523, Henning?

Comment: But note that this definition is not perfect either.  By this definition, we do not have $mn +1 = O(mn)$ for $m,n\ge 0$.  And even if we restrict to, say, $m,n\ge 1$, we do not have $mn = O((m-1)(n-1))$.