# Big O with multiple variables ($n,m$): Is $O((n+1)^m) = O(n^m)$?

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

In the [big O notation with multiple variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables) ($n,m$), is $O((n+1)^m) = O(n^m)$?

---

Details:

My intuition said yes, since adding a constant should neither have an effect in big O notation, even in a base. But since the exponent is also a variable and not a constant, I am not able to prove it. I tried for several definitions for Big O with multiple variables (such as the one on [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables) and the one on [this math.SE precious question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/353461/15523)), but did not find suitable estimates.

Comment: What are $n,m$?  Presumably you mean asymptotics in some sense.  In what sense?

Comment: $O$ is usually defined only for a single-variable functions. Do you intend one of $n,m$ to be fixed? If so, which one?

Comment: Big O can be defined for multiple variables. This is quite relevant for complexity considerations, since often the complexity depends on multiple parameters.

Comment: @GEdgar, yes, $n$, $m$ are both variables, and I am considering the limit behavior towards infinity.

Comment: There is no question here yet: compare "neither with n or m exceeding a positive constant K" with "n, m are both variables, and I am considering the limit behavior towards infinity".

Comment: @Did: There is no question here yet? What do you mean? The text in my bracket was meant as short explanation of how I tried proving it, i.e. resolving big O for multiple variables.

Comment: How to reconcile the two statements in my previous comment? One cannot.

Comment: @Did: Your quote is a quite misleading substring out of my sentence. I was not able to proof it either way: with n or m exceeding a positive constant K, or with using the distance. Anyway, I rewrote my whole question now because it was put on hold :(

Comment: I suggest that you slow down on disqualifying adjectives such as "misleading" when the quotes are actually taken from your comments. Rather, *explanations* about what you meant by these prima facie surprising statements would be welcome.

Comment: @Did: I said misleading because "neither" was related to proving, not to "n or m exceeding" as in your quote. I tried to explain above already, by rewriting my sentence with neither: I was not able to proof it either way: with n or m exceeding a positive constant K, or with using the distance. Furthermore, English is not my primary language...

Comment: So I tried to take your comments to heart and rewrote my question, but it is closed. Should I simply post this as a new question? Or can I trigger a reopen somehow, in spite of my low ranking?

Comment: Reputation has nothing to do with the matter. The matter is that, reading your question in its present formulation, one fails to understand how it was not already fully answered by @GEdgar yesterday. One can even refine this answer, noting that $(n+1)^m$ is not in $O(n^m)$ when $n$ and $m$ go to infinity, *unless $(n,m)$ is restricted to $m\leqslant Cn$ for some fixed $C$*. To sum up, instead of focusing on the reopening of your question and repeating "please elaborate", why don't you study the answer you already received?

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I had interpreted your previous comments as motivation to improve my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note if $m=n^2$, then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{n^m}{(n+1)^m}\right)
=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n^2} = 0
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is an interesting fact, but does not answer my question, since $n$ and $m$ need not be dependent in the definition of big O for multiple variables (see e.g. wikipedia or the cited paper there).

Comment: @Dave Sorry but this very much answers the question (by the negative).

Comment: Hey, no need to apologize ;) Great if it answers my question. Now I only have to understand it. Could you please elaborate, Did or GEdgar?

Comment: @DaveBall, if it were true that $(n+1)^m = O(n^m)$ for $n,m > 0$ then there would be a constant $C > 0$ such that $(n+1)^m \leq Cn^m$ for all $n,m > 0$, and then $$\frac{n^m}{(n+1)^m} \geq \frac{1}{C} > 0, \qquad n,m > 0. \tag{$*$}$$ But GEdgar showed that the quantity $n^m/(n+1)^m$ can get arbitrarily close to $0$ by choosing $n$ and $m$ in a certain way ($m=n^2$), and so $(*)$ cannot be true.